# How to check if a program exists in path using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, command, qprocess

I have this code:

```
QProcess* proceso = new QProcess();
QString programa = "unknow -v";
proceso->start(programa);
proceso->waitForFinished();

QString normal = proceso->readAllStandardOutput();
QString errores = proceso->readAllStandardError();

qDebug() << normal;
qDebug() << errores;
```

The output I get is:

> ""
>   ""

But I want get and error that says: Command not found.

Thanks in advance.

EDITED:

I found this solution using Qt:

```
 int result = system("unknow -v");
 if(result!=0) {
   qDebug() << "No está instalado nasm";
 } else {
   qDebug() << "Está instalado.";
 }
```

But I want get an output into a QString.

Comment: What is `unknow -v`, is that some string input from the user?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you, `unknow` is a program that should be in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch the value of your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) using `getenv("PATH")`  then split it on colons (or semi-colons for Windows), iterate on every directory there, test that it contains a `unknow` file,  etc....

So you don't need any Qt thing for that. Just plain C++ ([string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) operations).

<sup>(this is not bullet-proof: some other process might modify a directory in your `$PATH` between such a test and the actual start of process; but it should often be enough in practice)</sup>

On POSIX systems, you might run your command thru `sh -c` (e.g. run `sh -c 'unknow -v'`), but be careful of escapes and [code injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) (so check the string `unknow -v`  for things like single and double quotes, etc...)

You could also use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) perhaps using [which](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) but I don't recommend that (too complex).

I am not sure it is worth the trouble anyway. Why don't you simply just run the program.... I don't see much difference between a missing executable and a command failing for many other reasons.

Comment: `popen` would be pretty straightforward. Use `fgets` to read a line, then `pclose` it. If `pclose` returns non-zero, the command you were looking for didn't exist (`pclose` would return the exit code of the `which` command).

Comment: PS on Windows you can use `_popen` (stdio.h), as long as you're not doing a UWP build.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
QProcess program;
QString commandToStart= "unknown -v";
QStringList environment = program.systemEnvironment();
program.start(commandToStart);
bool started = program.waitForStarted();
if (!program.waitForFinished(10000)) // 10 Second timeout
    program.kill();

int exitCode = program.exitCode();
QString stdOutput = QString::fromLocal8Bit(program.readAllStandardOutput());
QString stdError = QString::fromLocal8Bit(program.readAllStandardError());
```

If `started` is `true`, the program could be started. That usually means, it was in the path. If it's `false`, check whether the path in `environment` is correct.

The `exitCode` is only helpful, if the process could actually be started and something else went wrong. If the program could *not* be started at all, `exitCode` will be `0` and `stdOutput` and `stdError` will be empty! That may be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about if you are able to run the command aka if the command exists on your system. This means NOT trying to launch it and see what happens, huge difference!

How about this?

I like the idea of `which` but it won't work under Windows, AFAIK.

```
    QProcess findProcess;
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << myCommand;
    findProcess.start("which", arguments);
    findProcess.setReadChannel(QProcess::ProcessChannel::StandardOutput);

    if(!findProcess.waitForFinished())
        return false; // Not found or which does not work

    QString retStr(findProcess.readAll());

    retStr = retStr.trimmed();

    QFile file(retStr);
    QFileInfo check_file(file);
    if (check_file.exists() && check_file.isFile())
        return true; // Found!
    else
        return false; // Not found!
```

Comment: You can use `where` under Windows.